# Invalid artifact repository: URL missing for repository

Tags: repository, maven-3

> I am trying to access my local repository but i am receiving below error:

```
 [ERROR] Invalid artifact repository: URL missing for repository internal @
```

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar refers to a non-existing file D:\apache-maven-3.0.3-bin\apache-maven-3.0.3\MavenJars @ line 23, column 16
 for project com.amruta.sample.spring:SpringMVCSample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT at D:\Workspace\SpringMVCSample\pom.xml

> Can anyone help me? I have done changes also in settings.xml for local repository

Comment: > I was able to correct it by providing path which contains name of the jar file too which is something like `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>D:/apache-maven-3.0.3-bin/apache-maven-3.0.3/MavenJars/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>`
> this absolute path has fixed my issue.

Comment: Something in your local maven repository adding as a system scoped dependency sounds weird. Isn't it ?

Comment: If i don't add as system scope how it would identify my local machine path to access the locally created repository.

Comment: you dont need much efforts to let maven access ur local repository.You just have to mention the path to your local repo in ur settings.xml .Whenever u want to access ur own developed artifact through mvn then just publish it first with mvn install command and ensure to specify correct artifact nm nd version in pom which wants to hv dependency on this.

Comment: Both things are required.. only settings.xml does not reslove the path for each specific jar.Initially i had done changes in settings.xml only but it has not worked and after proving absolute path it has started working